# toggle to get notified in swiftui

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode12

I want to be able to notify the user of my app every day at a specific time. in this example, the time is noon

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

struct Alert: View {
    
    @State var noon = false
    
    
    func noonNotify() {
        
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Meds"
        content.subtitle = "Take your meds"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        
        
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.hour = 14
        dateComponents.minute = 38
        
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
        
        // choose a random identifier
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
        // add our notification request
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack {
            
            Toggle(isOn: $noon) {
                Text("ThirdHour")
            }
            
            if noon {
                noonNotify()
            }
            
            Button("Request Permission") {
                
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
                    if success {
                        print("All set!")
                    } else if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
             
        }
    }
}
```

I created a func and when the toggle is true, the func will execute, but when it's false, then it won't. however, when I create an if statement, I get an error

> Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a function like that. Everything inside `var body: some View {` has to be a `View`, and `noonNotify()` doesn't return a `View`.

Instead, add an `onChange` block, which will get triggered whenever `noon` changes.

```
Toggle(isOn: $noon) {
    Text("ThirdHour")
}
.onChange(of: noon) { newValue in
    if newValue {
        noonNotify()
    }
}
```

Comment: I added an mp3 sound to my assets and want to use that as my notification sound. I added this to my code but it's not working, it just sounds the default sound
```
content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName(rawValue: "notifysound.mp3"))
```

 would you happen to know how to do that also?

Comment: @CodeBeast I haven't ever used notifications. But you should post that as a new question